# Execute Oracle Apex Process from HTML link

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have some custom HTML that creates a table on my page with a bunch of images. For each image I would like to create a  tag around it and call a process that has been defined in apex. How can I do this?

It seems that the only way to call processes is from a object that has been created by Oracle Apex such as a button item....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways:

1) You can set up your link to submit the page with a request like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSubmit('MYREQUEST')">...</a>
```

Then create a page process that runs when Request is equal to 'MYREQUEST'.

2) You can give your anchor an ID:

```
<a href="#" id="myAnchor">...</a>
```

Then create a Dynamic Action that fires on the Click event for the jQuery selector '#myAnchor' and executes PL/SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you need the *doSubmit* Javascript function because if you go to the

> report >> edit the column >> column link,

there is a *Request* field. You can put your request name there.

In page process condition type pick *Request = Expression* and put whatever you named the request.

Answer (score 0):

I find javascript more flexible. For example you can implement confirmation dialog with customized text message like followings:

```
SELECT col1,
       '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:if(confirm(''Submit with '||col1||' ?'')){doSubmit(''REQUEST1'');}">submit</a>' as link
  FROM tab1
```

Regards,
Igor